# Parallelize While Loop rgeos::gDistance

Tags: r, parallel-processing, distance, spatial

I have found a solution to my task, however, I need to improve its efficiency.

Now I will describe the task.

Starting from:

- a set of GPS points in the form of `SpatialPoints`;
- a roads shapefile in the form of `SpatialLinesDataFrame` obtained from OSM

I divide the `SpatialPoints` in `n` chunks and I sequentially apply the `while loop` to each chunk. This `while loop` consists of:

1. First, execute the `rgeos::gDistance()` function to each `point` in order to associate the `line` it belongs to. In fact, the output of `rgeos::gDistance()` is a massive `matrix` in which each `row` represent a point and each `column` represent the `distance` between that `point` and **all** the `lines` of the `SpatialLinesDataFrame`.
2. Then, thank to an `apply(gDistMatrix, 1, which.min))` I am able to reduce the `matrix` dimensions by keeping for each point **only** the closest line.
3. Save the result of this loop in the folder.

Finally, I can sequentially `read` all the files saved through the cycle and perform `rbind()`. The final objective is to find the street name of each GPS point.

This while lo
The speed bottleneck of this `while loop` are mainly two:

- the biggest bottleneck is caused by `rgeos::gDistance()` because for each single GPS, it compute the distance between all the line of the `SpatialLinesDataFrame` instead of just comparing (for example) the lines in a 200 metres radius
- another bottleneck is caused by the fact that this task is RAM-intensive rather than CPU-intensive. Therefore, my idea was parallelize the task in order to run 2 or 3 chunks at once.

Which is the best approach to solve the objective by run several chunks in parallel? It is important to consider that all the different chunks of `SpatialPoints` are compared to only one `SpatialLinesDataFrame`.

If I was not clear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: It'd help to have a small reproducible example, including input data, relevant sections of code, and expected output.

Comment: Can you give me an hint about how to make sample data for this case, please? Because I am using a massive dataset and a shapefile of a whole country